# Spring Boot WebSockets simple example

Tags: sockets, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a very basic example of a socket server in Spring Boot. 
I have the following classes

WebSocketConfigurer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/path");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler myHandler() {
        return new SimpleWebSocketHandler();
    }

}
```

TextWebSocketHandler:

```
public class SimpleWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleWebSocketHandler.class);


    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) {
        logger.debug("Opened new session in instance " + this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
            throws Exception {
        String echoMessage = message.getPayload();
        logger.debug(echoMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception)
            throws Exception {
        session.close(CloseStatus.SERVER_ERROR);
    }

}
```

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebSocketServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebSocketServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Then I have a C program that will open a socket and send simple text to a server.

When I try to send just plain text (e.g. “Hello”) over the socket, I get the following error message back to the client:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 18 Aug 2015 09:22:05 GMT
Connection: close
```

And the server displays a “Error parsing HTTP request header” message. I assume that is to be expected as the server is running in an embedded tomcat server and is only configured for HTTP.

When I then try to send a HTTP POST message as text from the C application e.g.

```
POST /path HTTP/1.0\r\n Content-Type: text/plain\r\n Content-Length: 5\r\n \r\n Hello
```

I get nothing on the server side and the connection on the client eventually just times out.

I’m missing something obvious?

Do I need to specify a controller class? Is that not covered when I register the web socket handler at a path?

Comment: You can't jump straight in with a WebSocket request. First, you need to send a well-formed HTTP request that asks to upgrade to a WebSocket connection. There's some more information [here](https://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html).

Comment: Ah, I see. I have a bit more work to do so! Thanks for the steer.